# Mapping class group of $S^p \times S^q$

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology, homology-cohomology, geometric-topology, mapping-class-group

If I understand correctly,

> (1) the mapping class group of $S^2 \times S^1$ is 
>   $$
> \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2,
> $$

- how do I understand these two generators?

> (2) What is the mapping class group of $S^p \times S^q$ in general?

Here $S^d$ is a d-sphere.

Comment: For the first question, if you consider a Heegard decomposition by two solid tori, then one of the generator interchange two solid torus, where the other generator will do a self map of degree 2 in each solid torus.

Comment: I guess by mapping class group you mean the oriented mapping class group. Then one generator is given by the antipodal map on $S^2$ cross a reflection on $S^1$ (the point being that they are orientation reversing on each fiber). The more interesting generator is given by writing $\gamma: S^1 \to SO(3)$ for a nontrivial loop, and writing $\varphi: S^2 \times S^1 \to S^2 \times S^1$ as $\varphi(x,\theta) = (\gamma_\theta(x), \theta)$. (Remember that $\gamma_\theta$ is a diffeomorphism $S^2 \to S^2$.)

Comment: It is a theorem of Hatcher that there is a homotopy equivalence $\text{Diff}(S^2 \times S^1) \simeq O(3) \times O(2) \times \Omega SO(3)$.

Comment: You know a lot, Mike and Abnubav. How do you define ΩSO(3) just make sure?

Comment: This is the based loop space, the space of maps $S^1 \to SO(3)$ sending $1$ to the identity. You could write just as well $O(2) \times LO(3)$, where $L$ is the *free loop space*, where we make no demands on $\gamma(1)$; the appearance of $O(3)$ in the above formula accounts for where $\gamma(1)$ goes.

Comment: Will the answer change for *unoriented mapping class group*? (where can I find some examples?)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think any answer deserves to start with a landscape of the field of mapping class groups, if for no reason but a word of warning.

Allow me to restrict to orientation-preserving transformations as a mild convenience.

For 2-dimensional manifolds, mapping class groups are very well-studied objects. For surfaces of genus $g \geq 2$, the mapping class group is a complicated (but finitely presented) group; it always surjects onto the group $\text{Sp}_{2g}(\Bbb Z)$, the group of automorphisms of $H_1(\Sigma_g;\Bbb Z) \cong \Bbb Z^{2g}$ preserving the intersection form $H_1(\Sigma_g) \otimes H_1(\Sigma_g) \to \Bbb Z$.

In general, the mapping class group of a closed oriented surface is isomorphic to $\text{Out}(\pi_1 \Sigma_g)$, the space of automorphisms $\pi_1 \Sigma_g \to \pi_1 \Sigma_g$, modulo those automorphisms induced by conjugation $\varphi_g: \gamma \mapsto g \gamma g^{-1}$.

For the 2-torus $S^1 \times S^1$, the mapping class group surjects onto $\text{Sp}_2(\Bbb Z) = SL_2(\Bbb Z)$, and in fact this surjection is an isomorphism.

In 3 dimensions, mapping class groups are still well-studied and well-understood. For any "Haken manifold", which is an irreducible 3-manifold (that is, every $S^2 \hookrightarrow M$ bounds a 3-ball) so that there is some surface of positive genus $\Sigma \hookrightarrow M$ which is "incompressible", meaning that no embedded loop in $\Sigma$ bounds an embedded disc in $M$ unless it already bounds a disc in $\Sigma$. $T^3$ is a simple example of a Haken manifold, with incompressible surface $T^2 \hookrightarrow T^3$.

Waldhausen proved that $\text{MCG}(Y) \cong \text{Out}(\pi_1 Y)$ for any Haken manifold $Y$. On our example above, $\text{Out}(\pi_1 T^3) = GL_3 \Bbb Z$; the orientation-preserving mapping class group is thus $SL_3 \Bbb Z$.

Now you cared about $S^1 \times S^2$; its mapping class group can be calculated as $(\Bbb Z/2)^2 = \text{Aut}(H_* S^1 \times S^2)$, where the first $\Bbb Z/2$ factor corresponds to a map that induces $-1$ on $H_i(S^1 \times S^2)$ (for $i = 1,2$), and the third factor corresponds to the nontrivial loop in $SO(3)$.

If you want to get a good feel for mapping class groups of 3-manifolds, you can't do much better than starting with Hatcher's note [A 50-year view of diffeomorphism groups](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/Papers/Diff%28M%292012.pdf).

Up through here, you could use homeomorphisms or diffeomorphisms more or less interchangeably.

In dimension 4 essentially nothing is known. Danny Ruberman has a paper constructing an infinite sequence of simply connected 4-manifolds $X_n$ such that the map from the *smooth* mapping class group (of diffeomorphisms mod smooth isotopy) to the *continuous* mapping class group (of homeomorphisms mod continuous isotopy) has infinitely generated kernel. That's wild! It is worth noting that this does *not* prove that $\text{MCG}_{smooth}(X_n)$ is infinitely generated, but it seems plausible.

In dimensions up to 3, these groups were actually the same. I will stick with smooth mapping class groups from now on.

The best you can say is a recent theorem of Gabai (called the 4D lightbulb theorem), which has as a corollary that $\text{MCG}(S^2 \times D^2, \text{rel } \partial)/\text{MCG}(D^4, \text{rel } \partial) = *$ - that is, every diffeomorphism of $S^2 \times D^2$ rel the boundary is given by doing some diffeomorphism of the 4-ball somewhere in the interior. It seems very difficult to extend this to say anything about $\text{MCG}(S^2 \times S^2)$.

In dimensions $d \geq 5$, there is good, and there is bad. The good: If $M$ is simply connected, then [Sullivan proved](https://mathoverflow.net/a/161775/40804) that $\text{MCG}(M)$ is finitely presented. (This can go as badly as possible when $M$ has infinite fundamental group, eg the example of $T^n$ given there.)

The bad: These groups are somewhere between very hard and impossible to calculate.

---

We restrict to $S^p \times S^q$ where $p + q \geq 5$ and $\text{min}(p, q) \geq 2$. There is a dichotomy between the cases where $p = q$ and where $p \neq q$. This is analagous to the difference between $S^1 \times S^1$ and $S^1 \times S^2$: the point is that $\text{Aut}(H_p(S^p \times S^p)) = SL_2 \Bbb Z$ when $p$ is odd (and $D_8$ when $p$ is even; the difference is whether the intersection form is symmetric or skew-symmetric). However, there are many fewer automorphisms of $H_p(S^p \times S^q) = \Bbb Z$ where $p \neq q$ (there is just multiplication by -1).

Now to quote some results.

First, for $S^p \times S^p$, our starting point is [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0905.0423) by Diarmuid Crowley. Just like in the statement of Gabai's theorem above, we should start by quotienting by the action of diffeomorphisms of the $2p$-ball (so that we don't really have to think about them). Call $$\text{Aut}(S^p \times S^p) := \text{MCG}(S^p \times S^p)/\text{MCG}(D^{2p}, \text{rel } \partial).$$

For $p = 3, 7$ he identifies $\text{Aut}(S^p \times S^p) \cong \Bbb Z^2 \oplus SL_2 \Bbb Z$ (the $\Bbb Z^2$ factor acts trivially on homology). When $p = 4j-1 > 7$, the $SL_2 \Bbb Z$ is replaced by automorphisms of a more complicated quadratic form.

It seems you should be able to get more results about these manifolds from the article of Kreck [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/225650774_Isotopy_classes_of_diffeomorphisms_of_k-1-connected_almost-parallelizable_2k-manifolds), but I did not have the patience to work out the answer.

When $p \neq q$, here are some results.

First, Turner in 1969 [calculated](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF01418871.pdf), when $k < l < 2k - 3$, that the mapping class group of diffeomorphisms that act *trivially* on homology is given as a semidirect product $$(\pi_l SO_{k+1} \oplus \Gamma_{k+l+1}) \rtimes \pi_k SO,$$ where $\Gamma_{j}$ is the group of oriented exotic $j$-spheres modulo oriented diffeomorphism. (This mapping class group should be called $\pi_0 \text{SDiff}(M)$, and fits into a short exact sequence $$0 \to \pi_0 \text{SDiff}(M) \to \text{MCG}^+(M) \to \Bbb Z/2.$$

I will provide one example not in that case: the mapping class group acting trivially on the homology $S^2 \times S^3$ (which fits into a sequence as above). Diarmuid Crowley [here](http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/Talk:5-manifolds:_1-connected) says that this group is calculated by work of Fang as being isomorphic to $\Omega_6^\text{spin}(\Bbb{CP}^\infty)$. With some help from homotopy theorists on this site, a difficult calculation shows that this is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z^2$.

---

I hope this shows how wild, interesting, and very difficult to study are mapping class groups (and diffeomorphism groups) in high dimensions.

Comment: Thanks accepted -- Related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3094518/